# IHostEnvironment and no DI in Startup constructor .NET Core 3+

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

We are building .NET Core microservices.

Many of our microservices use `HttpClient` logging through `ConfigurePrimaryMessageHandler()`

With .NET Core 2+ our approach had been to

`services.AddHttpClient().ConfigurePrimarymessageHandler()` in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs`.  We had to pass in a `ILogger<T>` here and we would get that by injecting it into our Startup constructor.

Now that we have migrated to `IHostEnvironment` we can no longer use DI to inject `ILogger<T>` into Startup constructor AND we can't inject `IServiceCollection` into `Configure()`.

One idea I had was to create the `HttpClientBuilder`, store a reference to it and then do the `ConfigurePrimaryMessageHandler` in `Configure`...  This did NOT work.  I'm assuming because once it is built, it is built so you need to do it in `ConfigureServices`.

So I ended up coming up with a nasty hack that works but it feels yucky:

I have an `ILogger<T>` as a protected member of my `Startup.cs`.

I pass that in (its null) into my `HttpClientBuilder`s...

Then in `Configure()` I inject `ILogger<T>` and set the protected member variable.

Yuck!

It kind of looks like this:

```
class Startup
{
    protected ILogger<HttpClientLoggingHandler> _logHack;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<T>().ConfigurePrimaryMessageHandler(()=>{ new 
        HttpClientLoggingHandler(_logHack, otherstuff) });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder bld, ILogger<T> logForHack, otherstufffordi)
    {
         _logHack = logForHack;   // note this works, but is this really a good design pattern?
    }
}
```

So this does work...  But it doesn't feel like a really great design pattern.  Any advice out there anyone?  Is this really the approach we should be taking?  Feel like something was missed here when we migrated to `IHostEnvironment`.

Comment: You mean, migrated to IWebHostEnvironment?

Comment: I don't understand the question - what you posted is how .NET Core 2.2 worked too. Startup.cs's constructor did *not* receive the application's logger or DI. It received the *hoster's* logger. The hoster's logger is only needed for logging during configuration - before the application's logging configuration even runs

Comment: What happened before is that your configured HttpClientHandler would end up using the hoster's logging configuration, not the application's. If you wanted to add eg Serilog, store different messages in different files etc, HttpClientHandler would bypass all this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do `.ConfigurePrimaryMessageHandler<HttpClientLoggingHandler>();`, provided the `HttpClientLoggingHandler` is registered.

The lambda overloads for `ConfigurePrimaryMessageHandler` also can pass you an `IServiceProvider`. From there, call `sp.GetRequiredService<T>`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I was a little late, but just had a chance to validate this.  It works well.